# HealthConnect - Permission Dialog not working in release mode

Tags: android, proguard

App crashes when the app is running in release mode with proguard enabled.

Here is the Crash report.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown data type name h0
   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2429)
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.service.IHealthDataService$Stub$Proxy.getGrantedPermissions(IHealthDataService.java:414)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.impl.ServiceBackedHealthDataClient.getGrantedPermissions$lambda-1(ServiceBackedHealthDataClient.kt:93)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.impl.ServiceBackedHealthDataClient.$r8$lambda$hhWerw-hyBNCC_kPGtX4mZNDQdM(ServiceBackedHealthDataClient.kt)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.impl.ServiceBackedHealthDataClient$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$605e77fbbfc877805d8dd88d131a334eb9370ed10712fd7118bc908c2d0b7ca2$0.execute(ServiceBackedHealthDataClient.java:6)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.impl.ipc.Client$3.execute(Client.java:279)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.impl.ipc.internal.ServiceConnection.execute(ServiceConnection.java:243)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.impl.ipc.internal.ServiceConnection.enqueue(ServiceConnection.java:200)
   at androidx.health.platform.client.impl.ipc.internal.ConnectionManager.handleMessage(ConnectionManager.java:123)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Any Proguard rules should I need to add for health Connect API?

Comment: do you have any other set proguard rules outside of the default ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Aug. 3, 2022**:

As of version 1.0.0-alpha03, this has been fixed on the library's end.

Links :

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/health#health-connect-client-1.0.0-alpha03
- https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2153498/2/health/health-connect-client/proguard-rules.pro

---

For the meantime time, you can add these rules into your proguard file:

```
-keep public class androidx.health.** {
  public protected private *;
}
-dontwarn androidx.health.**
```

It is quite overarching to ignore the entire lib at the moment, but at least it gets your project to build under release.

Comment: any advises while using 1.1.0-alpha02 ? It seems like I do have something similar but proguard rules above do not help. In Android Studio mode it works perfect.

Comment: @nKognito, can you create a new post regarding your issue? I'd be glad to help

Comment: thnx, but at the end my issue was unrelated. Apparently Google folks restrict an access to health connect, one need to write them an email to enable it, that's why my release version didn't work